# Pandas and combine stacked bar and line graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I've grouped pandas dataframe:

```
        DailyTests  pos_DailyTests  percentOfPositive
Week                                               
44          1079              45               4.00
45         14593             706               4.64
46         18290            1003               5.14
47         19271            1237               6.07
48         12258             938               7.04
```

I want to draw graphs from this data. the "Week" is x axis and the first two columns are stacked bar grahps and the third one should be line graph. But the line is not displayed

My code:

```
fig , ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
data_con2.plot(kind='bar', stacked = True, ax=ax1, y = ['DailyTests','pos_DailyTests'])
data_con2.plot(kind='line', ax=ax2, y = 'percentOfPositive', color="red")
ax1.set_ylabel('Tests in day')
ax2.set_ylabel('percent of positives')
```

Example graph is looking next:

[Example graph - stacked bars but not the line graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8seE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

There reason why your code is not working because kind = 'bar' and 'line' both plots the x-axis differently. Simple way to solve this is to convert week into a string type. One more thing the line plot is difficult to see as 'percentOfPositive' has low values as compare to other two columns but it is there.

```
df['Week'] = df['Week'].astype("string") 
ax = df[['Week', 'DailyTests', 'pos_DailyTests']].plot(x='Week', kind='bar',  stacked=True )
df[['Week', 'percentOfPositive']].plot(x='Week', color ='black' ,marker='o',ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

[image]